# Permission problem with equivs-build

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, fakeroot

I am trying to install a vanilla texlive 2018 distribution on a ubuntu 16.04 machine following this guide: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373

However in the step `equivs-build texlive-local` (executed as root) I get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 175: debian/rules: Permission denied
Error in the build process: exit status 126
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1007573/15811

Comment: Thanks, but where is `debian/rules` located? I searched for it and tried chmod a+x `/usr/share/equivs/template/debian/rules` but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created the temporary directory for the equivs build process in `/tmp/` and `/tmp` was mounted with `noexec` flag for security reasons.

Copying the build directory to another place did make it work, as well es remounting `/tmp` without `noexec` flag.